# How to pass dynamically generated textbox values to the controller from view?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have generated dynamic textboxes using jQuery on button click. I want to pass their values to the controller using AJAX. I am using the `form.serialize` method.
 i can see the value when i alert .But in the controller it becomes null

```
$("#add").click(function() {
  $("#mydiv").append($("<div class='row' id='row'> <div class='col-md-4'><div class='form-group'><div class='col-md-10'><input type='text' name='vname[]'class='form-control' placeholder='Vazhipad Name' /></div></div></div><div class='col-md-4'><div class='form-group'><div class='col-md-10'><input type='text' name='vprize[]'class='form-control' placeholder='Vazhipad Prize' /> </div></div> </div><div class='form-group'><div class='col-md-10'><button type='button' id='btnRemove' class='btn btn-primary btnRemove'>-</button></div></div></div></div>"))
});

$("#sub").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/Admin/AddVazhipad",
    type: "POST",
    data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      alert("Success");
    },
    failure: function(data) {
      alert("Failed");
    },
  });
```

```cs
public class Vazhipad
{
  [Required] public int vid { get; set; }
  [Required] public int templeid { get; set; }
  [Required] public List<string> vname { get; set; }
  [Required] public List<float> vprize { get; set; }   
}
```

[image: The value becomes null in the controller]

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer.What i did is named the Textbox name "vname[]" to "vname".It works perfectly now